# How to enable and disable javascript functions?

Tags: javascript

```
             if(tmpStr == tmp+value)
             {
                i=1;
                action = null;
                action2 = null;
             }
             if(tmpStr1 == tmp+value)
             {
                i=0;
                            action();//not working
                            action2();//not working
             }
             for(i;i<=14; i++)
             {
                 if(tmp!="movie"+i) 
                 {
                    document.getElementById("movie"+i).sndToAS("resume");
                 }
             }

         }
         function action()
         {
            document.getElementById("movie0").sndToAS("pause");
         }
         function action2()
         {
            if(tmp != "movie0")
            {
                document.getElementById("movie0").sndToAS("pause");

            }
         }
```

Comment: Could you elaborate please? I don't get what you're asking here

Comment: Actually I am using JS for communicationg with flash audio and video players. My code little bit larger. I wants to know is there any `Listener` like
`addEventListener` and `removeEventListener`?.

Comment: In a simple way... how to disable and enable functions?

Comment: Downvote?????...pls put down a comment.

Comment: I didn't downvote it but I wouldn't qualify this as a well elaborated question. Just the title and code won't cut it. Also try reducing your problem to the minimum lines needed to understand the problem.

Comment: What is the need for elaborate??? I know how to deactivate the functions and I don't know how to reactivate the functions. This code is enough for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do something like this

```
function actionFunc(){
    document.getElementById("movie0").sndToAS("pause");
}
function action2Func()
{
    if(tmp != "movie0"){
     document.getElementById("movie0").sndToAS("pause");

    }
}

window.action = actionFunc;
window.action2 = action2Func;

if(tmpStr == tmp+value)
{
    id=1;
    window.action = null;
    window.action2 = null;
}
if(tmpStr1 == tmp+value)
{
    id=0;
    window.action = actionFunc;
    window.action2 = action2Func;
}
```

Then when you want to call your functions all you have to do is

```
action();
action2();
```

but your going to want to check if the are set before calling them

I believe thats what your after

or do something like this

```
function action(){
    if (window.actionEnabled)
    {
       document.getElementById("movie0").sndToAS("pause");
    }
}
function action2()
{
    if (window.action2Enabled)
    {
       if(tmp != "movie0"){
         document.getElementById("movie0").sndToAS("pause");
       }
    }
}

window.actionEnabled = true;
window.action2Enabled = true;

if(tmpStr == tmp+value)
{
    id=1;
    window.actionEnabled = false;
    window.action2Enabled = false;
}
if(tmpStr1 == tmp+value)
{
    id=0;
    window.actionEnabled = true;
    window.action2Enabled = true;
}
```

then you don't have to check if the are enabled just call them and they will work or want depending on if they are enabled

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want a function to execute when in a particular state, I would wrap your function do a state check and then a return if in an inappropriate state.

```
function action(obj){
   if(obj.state == <a state you dont want to execute>)
     return;

   action();
} 

function action(){
   document.getElementById("movie0").sndToAS("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just declare a global variable

```
var stopfunction=false;
```

and as a first line in your function

```
if (stopfunction) return;
```